Can you identify what is making this noise when I turn the wheel?
I have a Honda Odyssey 2011 that is making some humming noises when I turn the wheel. I can hear it at slow speeds. Please review it in this video: https://photos.app.goo.gl/VVbFt3YC7pb8yJAe7
Can you tell what the problem is?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Wow, that is an odd noise. I've never heard anything like that before out of a vehicle ... very strange!

It sounds to me like your brake discs are ringing. Think of a wet finger rubbing on a wine glass rim. Same principle. Something is encouraging one or both discs to ring at its resonant frequency via the stick-slip phenomenon.
But what's rubbing? It could be that one or more of your brake pads is glazed from overheating. Have you ever smelled that characteristic hot brake smell when you get out of the vehicle? If so, a caliper could be sticking. If a glazed brake pad is rubbing "just so" on a brake disc, it's almost like a violin bow rubbing on a violin string.
How to test the theory?
Fill a pump spray bottle with clean water and take it with you as you drive. You didn't mention it, but I have a feeling that conditions have to be just right for this sound to occur. When that happens and you can reliably get it to squeal, turn the wheels to one side and thoroughly spray the brake discs with water on both sides, outboard and inboard. Jump back in and see if the squeal has stopped, at least briefly.
If so, the theory is confirmed. Disassemble to inspect the brake pads for uneven wear and glazing. Uneven wear could be from a defect in the caliper or a collapsed brake hose. Glazing, if not from a dragging caliper, would be from a sequence of high speed, high deceleration stops without sufficient time to cool.
Please let us know.

FYI it turns out this noise happens while I am turning but the wheels are not rolling.

@sethbro In the video it only happens while the vehicle is moving. In any case, it still sounds like resonant ringing of something so please check your serpentine belt tensioner; it should be keeping the serp belt very tight, to deflect only slightly between pulleys with light finger pressure. If loose, the belt can slip when the accessory (such as power steering pump) is working extra hard such as at extremes of steering angle. The belt could make the power steering pump pulley ring as it slips by the same stick-slip phenomenon.

@sethbro And if happening only at lock-to-lock extremes of steering angle while trying to force the steering wheel past its natural stop, this could be the sound of a hydraulic pressure relief valve either in the power steering pump itself or the steering gear.
